# jQuery ajax, name of data field attached with var

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How is it possible to add a variable to the name of the data field I want to send information to through ajax.

Here's an example of my code.

```
              var qty = $('#qty_'+value).val();

            $.ajax({

                url: 'ajax/save_order-2.php?id='+value,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {

                    qty_'+value': qty

                },
                dataType: 'HTML',
                success: function(order_info_response){

                    console.log(order_info_response);
                }

            });
```

How do I attach the variable "value" to the data name "qty" just like I did with the var qty.

What is the proper format for doing this without getting Syntax Error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to creare array and pass it

```
        var qty = $('#qty_'+value).val();
        var data = {};
        data["qty_"+value] = qty;
        $.ajax({

            url: 'ajax/save_order-2.php?id='+value,
            type: 'POST',
            data,
            dataType: 'HTML',
            success: function(order_info_response){

                console.log(order_info_response);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating object outside of `$.ajax()` , adjusting `+` operator to before string `"value"`

```
var data = {};

var qty = $('#qty_' + value).val();

data[qty_ + "value"] = qty;

$.ajax({

  url: 'ajax/save_order-2.php?id=' + value,
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'HTML',
  success: function(order_info_response) {
    console.log(order_info_response);
  }

});
```